# Prevent user from editing source code using Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Google chrome or maybe other browsers allows client side editing of html source. Is there a way to prevent this so users cannot do it on a site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; that is fundamentally impossible.

You can never have any level of control over the client.